# python compare a list of lists efficiently

Tags: python, list, set

I have a long list of long lists so efficiency is an issue for me. I wondered if there was a neater way of comparing a list of lists other than looping over a list within a loop of the same list (easier to see by example)

```
matchList=[]
myList = [ ('a',[1,2,3]), ('b', [2,3,4]), ('c', [3,4,5]), ('d', [4,5,6]) ]

tup_num=1
for tup in myList:
    for tup2 in myList[tup_num:]:
        id=str(tup[0])+':'+str(tup2[0])
        matches=set(tup[1]) & set(tup2[1])
        matchList.append((id,matches))
    tup_num+=1

print matchList
```

Output:

```
[('a:b', set([2, 3])), ('a:c', set([3])), ('a:d', set([])), ('b:c', set([3, 4])), ('b:d', set([4])), ('c:d', set([4, 5]))]
```

This works and doesn't repeat comparisons but I'm sure there must be a better way of doing it.

Cheers

Comment: why are you sure that there is another way? you need to compare all elements. How can you do it without looking at each if they all match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> matchList = []
>>> myList = [('a',[1,2,3]), ('b', [2,3,4]), ('c', [3,4,5]), ('d', [6,7,8])]
>>> matchList = [
...     ('{}:{}'.format(key1, key2), set(lst1) & set(lst2))
...     for (key1, lst1), (key2, lst2) in itertools.combinations(myList, 2)
... ]
>>> matchList
[('a:b', set([2, 3])), ('a:c', set([3])), ('a:d', set([])), ('b:c', set([3, 4])), ('b:d', set([])), ('c:d', set([]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

- Convert those list to sets at first. That's an O(n) operation, which better avoided.
- itertools.combinations is faster and easier.

Like this:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> l
[('a', [1, 2, 3]), ('b', [2, 3, 4]), ('c', [3, 4, 5]), ('d', [6, 7, 8])]
>>> l = [(i, set(j)) for i, j in l]
>>> l
[('a', {1, 2, 3}), ('b', {2, 3, 4}), ('c', {3, 4, 5}), ('d', {8, 6, 7})]
>>> [("%s:%s" % (l1[0], l2[0]), l1[1] & l2[1]) for l1, l2 in combinations(l, 2)]
[('a:b', {2, 3}), ('a:c', {3}), ('a:d', set()), ('b:c', {3, 4}), ('b:d', set()), ('c:d', set())]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using composition and generators makes it clear:

```
from itertools import combinations

matchList = []
myList = [ ('a',[1,2,3]), ('b', [2,3,4]), ('c', [3,4,5]), ('d', [4,5,6]) ]

def sets(items):
  for name, tuple in items:
    yield name, set(tuple)

def matches(sets):
  for a, b in combinations(sets, 2):
    yield ':'.join([a[0], b[0]]), a[1] & b[1]

print list(matches(sets(myList)))


>>> [('a:b', set([2, 3])), ('a:c', set([3])), ('a:d', set([])), ('b:c', set([3, 4])), ('b:d', set([4])), ('c:d', set([4, 5]))]
```