# Exhaustive combinations of lists in python

Tags: python, combinations, nested-lists, python-itertools

I have a long list of lists in Python that looks something like this:

```
myList=[

('a',[1,2,3,4,5]),
('b',[6,7,8,9,10]),
('c',[1,3,5,7,9]),
('d',[2,4,6,8,10]),
('e',[4,5,6,7,8])

]
```

And I would like to enumerate the common values exhaustively

```
('a:b', ),
('a:c', [1,3,5]),
('a:d', [2,4]),
('a:e', [4,5]),
('b:c', [7,9]),
('b:d', [6,8,10]),

('a:c:e', [5]),
('b:c:e', [7]),
('b:d:e', [6,8]),
```

and the same for groups of four, five, six until all common values have been identified (assuming the lists were longer)

Is this possible using the `itertools` library or sets or a combination of the above?

I have been trying to write a function that loops over the original list for every new list I generate but It hasn't been going well!

Here is what I have:

```
def findCommonElements(MyList):

    def sets(items):
        for name, tuple in items:
            yield name, set(tuple)

    def matches(sets):
       for a, b in combinations(sets, 2):
           yield ':'.join([a[0], b[0]]), a[1] & b[1]

    combinationsSet=list(matches(sets(keywordCount)))

    combinationsList=[]
    for pair,tup in combinationsSet:
        setList=list(tup)
        combinationsList.append((pair, len(setList), setList))
    combinationsList=sorted(combinationsList,key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) #this just sorts the list by the number of common elements

    return combinationsList
```

Comment: you may recognise part of the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790275/python-compare-a-list-of-lists-efficiently thanks to Triptych

Comment: Kudos for posting the code, but your question is still way too vague. "It hasn't been going well?" What's the problem?

Comment: Why not a dictionary?

Comment: In your case maybe try something with set(list1).intersection(list2)

Comment: Just a minor point - what you have a list of tuples, not a list of lists. Secondly, are the tuples ordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You can try to use `itertools.combinations` with `itertools.chain`

nit very good example but It should work.
I will use  `itertools` and generators here:

```
lengthes = xrange(2, len(myList)+1)
combinations_list = (itertools.combinations(myList, i) for i in lengthes)
combinations = itertools.chain.from_iterable(combinations_list)
def find_intersection(lists):
    res = set(lists[0])
    for data in lists:
        res &= set(data)
    return res
result = [(':'.join(i), list(find_intersection(v))) for i, v in (zip(*x) for x in combinations)]
```

or just `itertools.combinations`

```
def findCommonElements(MyList):

    combinationsList=[]

    for seq_len in xrange(2, len(MyList)+1):
        for combination in combinations:
            for indexes, values in zip(*combination):
                intersection = reduce(lambda x, y: x & set(y[1]), 
                                      values, set(values[0]))
                if intersection:
                    combinationsList.appen(':'.join(indexes), intersection)
        return combinationsList
```

Comment: Boiled down to the smallest possible solution.  Now explain ;-)

Comment: If we change all variable names to single letters and shrink the white spaces, this will be a good contender for codegolf. :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using dictionaries I just whipped up:

```
def iter_recursive_common_elements(lists, max_depth=None):
    data = [{k:set(v) for k,v in lists.iteritems()}] # guarantee unique
    depth = 0

    def get_common_elements(lists, base):
        d = {}
        for k, v in lists.iteritems():
            merged = k.split(':')
            potential = set(base).difference(merged)
            for target in potential:
                d[':'.join(sorted(merged+[target]))] = v.intersection(base[target])
        return d if d else None

    while True:
        ret = get_common_elements(data[depth], data[0])
        if not ret:
            break
        data.append(ret)
        depth += 1
        yield data[depth]
        if max_depth and depth > max_depth:
            break
```

---

Using it is simple enough:

```
lists = {'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
        'b':[6,7,8,9,10],
        'c':[1,3,5,7,9],
        'd':[2,4,6,8,10],
        'e':[4,5,6,7,8]}

for x in iter_recursive_common_elements(lists):
    print x

>>> 
{'d:e': set([8, 4, 6]), 'a:b': set([]), 'a:c': set([1, 3, 5]), 'a:d': set([2, 4]), 'a:e': set([4, 5]), 'b:e': set([8, 6, 7]), 'b:d': set([8, 10, 6]), 'b:c': set([9, 7]), 'c:d': set([]), 'c:e': set([5, 7])}
{'a:b:d': set([]), 'a:b:e': set([]), 'a:b:c': set([]), 'a:c:e': set([5]), 'c:d:e': set([]), 'a:c:d': set([]), 'b:c:d': set([]), 'b:c:e': set([7]), 'b:d:e': set([8, 6]), 'a:d:e': set([4])}
{'b:c:d:e': set([]), 'a:b:c:e': set([]), 'a:b:c:d': set([]), 'a:c:d:e': set([]), 'a:b:d:e': set([])}
{'a:b:c:d:e': set([])}
```

---

Can also clean up the output to match more what you wanted:

```
for x in iter_recursive_common_elements(lists):
    for k, v in sorted(x.items()):
        if v:
            print '(%s) : %s' % (k.replace(':', ', '), list(v))

>>> 
(a, c) : [1, 3, 5]
(a, d) : [2, 4]
(a, e) : [4, 5]
(b, c) : [9, 7]
(b, d) : [8, 10, 6]
(b, e) : [8, 6, 7]
(c, e) : [5, 7]
(d, e) : [8, 4, 6]
(a, c, e) : [5]
(a, d, e) : [4]
(b, c, e) : [7]
(b, d, e) : [8, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

```
from itertools import combinations

myList = [
    ('a', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
    ('b', [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),
    ('c', [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]),
    ('d', [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]),
    ('e', [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),
]


def print_commons(mList):

    letters = map(lambda l: l[0], mList)
    mdict = dict(mList)

    for i in range(2, len(letters) + 1):
        for comb in combinations(letters, i):  # generate all possible combinations
            sequence = [mdict[letter] for letter in comb]  # get the corresponding lists 
            uniques = reduce(lambda x, y: set(x).intersection(y), sequence)  # reduce the lists until only the common elements remain
            print('{} : {}'.format(comb, list(uniques)))

print_commons(myList)

('a', 'b') : []
('a', 'c') : [1, 3, 5]
('a', 'd') : [2, 4]
('a', 'e') : [4, 5]
('b', 'c') : [9, 7]
('b', 'd') : [8, 10, 6]
('b', 'e') : [8, 6, 7]
('c', 'd') : []
('c', 'e') : [5, 7]
('d', 'e') : [8, 4, 6]
('a', 'b', 'c') : []
('a', 'b', 'd') : []
('a', 'b', 'e') : []
('a', 'c', 'd') : []
('a', 'c', 'e') : [5]
('a', 'd', 'e') : [4]
('b', 'c', 'd') : []
('b', 'c', 'e') : [7]
('b', 'd', 'e') : [8, 6]
('c', 'd', 'e') : []
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') : []
('a', 'b', 'c', 'e') : []
('a', 'b', 'd', 'e') : []
('a', 'c', 'd', 'e') : []
('b', 'c', 'd', 'e') : []
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e') : []
```

Comment: your function returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

I'd split it into three parts. One, your list in unwieldy, it'd be better to store it as a dictionary with the letter as key, and a set of values as the value:

```
def make_dict(myList):
    return dict((letter, set(values)) for letter, values in myList)
```

Second, all the possible combinations. I think combinations of length 1 (the letters by themselves) aren't interesting, so you want the combinations of length 2 to the maximum:

```
from itertools import combinations
def all_combinations(letters):
   for length in range(2, len(letters) + 1):
       for combination in combinations(letters, length):
           yield combination
```

And third, a function that given that created dictionary, and a combination, yields the numbers that are common to all the letters:

```
def common_values(the_dict, combination):
    # This can be made shorter with reduce(), but I hate it
    values_so_far = the_dict[combination[0]]
    for letter in combination[1:]:
        value_so_far = values_so_far & the_dict[letter]
    return values_so_far
```

And then all three can be easily combined:

```
the_dict = make_dict(myList)
for combination in all_combinations(the_dict):
    print combination, common_values(the_dict, combination)
```